# Is it right to set setSmallestDisplacement to 0 in LocationListener

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-fragments, locationmanager

I am trying to get user location, when he crosses `1000 meters` or if he is in the same place for 6 Hours.

First condition was working fine by implementing `LocationListener`. But for second condition i need some handler that will keep running  every second, so that i know when  the specified time has passed.

I am able to calculate the difference between last position and current position of user, so if i remove `mLocationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(distanceCriteria);` , and set interval to 1 seconds, then i can get both location and the timer.

It keeps calling `onLocationChanged` every seconds, and giving me user location on each second, I can calculate the difference between last saved and current location.

My Question is that is this the right approach or will it effect the battery if locationManager is calling itself on every second, or any other disadvantage of using this approach

Comment: Please mention what is your `setInterval` and `setFastestInterval` value is